# Display only one instance of same object in model (Distinct other instances of same object)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am building a simple question and answer site and I am trying to implement a functionality in which user can `upload 4 answers But I am trying to hide show only any one answer` And this is showing all the answers related to a question.

**For Example :-** question_a has 4 answers then i am trying to show any one of them.

models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    marked = models.BooleanField(booleanField)

class Answer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question_of = models.ForeignKey(BlogPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

views.py

```
def page(request):
    query_2 = Answer.objects.filter(question_of__marked=True)[:1]

    context = {'query_2':query_2}
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```

In this query I am trying to show Answers of qustions which have `marked=True` and i am also trying to show only one answer of a question But it is showing 4.

And after using [:1] it is only showing result in all.

- I also tried `.distinct()` but it made no effect on results.

**What i am trying to do ?**

I am trying to show first answer of every question that has `marked=True`

I will really appreciate your Help. Thank You

Comment: `Answer.objects.filter(question_of__marked=True)` this will return all answers where question is marked as True. If you want answers of any one question filter question field with the question instance or question_id. Also can you show page.html

Comment: if you want to show an answer related to a question,then your view(page) is not valid you should change it.

Comment: I am trying to only answer answer of every question

Answer (score 0):

This will take the first row from the query

```
query_2 = Answer.objects.filter(question_of__marked=True).first()
```

This will take only an answer id for each group (for the code below is grouped by question_of)

```
query_2 = Answer.objects.filter(
    question_of__marked=True
).values(
    'question_of'
).annotate(
    selected_id=Max(id) # Assuming id is the pk for Answer model
).distinct().values_list('selected_id')

# Query again using the filtered ids
out_query = Answer.objects.filter(question_of__marked=True, id__in=query_2)
```

Comment: It is only showing one result but I am trying to show every question's first answer.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I've edited the answer by adding aggregation, hope it's help

Comment: It's Okay But It is showing error :- `Cannot resolve expression type, unknown output_field`

Answer (score 0):

The answer model has a one to many relationship with the blogPost model not the question model change that and it should work.
And the second thing is to pass the question you want get the first answer of. Finally change the BooleanField that you are passing as a parameter and use a default if wanted.

```
marked = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def page(request):
quest = Question.objects.get(pk=1) # the quest obj 
query_2 = [Answer.objects.filter(question_of__marked=True)[:1]]
context = {'query_2':query_2}
return render(request, 'page.html', context)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As i mentioned that i also tried using **[:1]**, And it is showing only one result of whole model.

Comment: I do not understand what do you want exactly.